# Create Multi-Series Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts

I would like to make a multi-series chart in VB.NET. How many series depends on the department and the data gathered from a datatabe which is collected from a datagridview.

```
Department Period_Shown Rate_Int
EMW 2018 0.94
EMW 2019 0.55
ACH 2015 0.29
ACH 2016 0.52
ACH 2017 0.56
ACH 2018 0.63
ACH 2019 0.57
```

At the end, the chart shown one series only, it is different from my idea (i.e.: Department 'EMW' is series 1 and Department 'ACH' is series 2).

Here is the source code for the chart control:

```
Dim dtRate As New DataTable("dtRate")
'Add columns to DataTable.
For Each cell As TableCell In GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells
    dtRate.Columns.Add(cell.Text)
Next
'Loop through the GridView and copy rows.
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    dtRate.Rows.Add()
    For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
        dtRate.Rows(row.RowIndex)(i) = row.Cells(i).Text
    Next
Next
Dim Departments As List(Of String) = (From p In dtRate.AsEnumerable() _
                               Select p.Field(Of String)("Department")).Distinct().ToList()
If RateChart.Series.Count() = 1 Then
    RateChart.Series.Remove(RateChart.Series(0))
End If
'Loop through the Departments.
For Each UserDepartment As String In Departments
    'Get the Shown_Period for each Department.
    Dim x As Integer() = (From p In dtRate.AsEnumerable() _
                          Where p.Field(Of String)("Department") = UserDepartment _
                          Order By p.Field(Of Integer)("Shown_Period") _
                          Select p.Field(Of Integer)("Shown_Period")).ToArray()
    'Get the Num_Int of Orders for each Department.
    Dim y As Integer() = (From p In dtRate.AsEnumerable() _
                          Where p.Field(Of String)("Department") = UserDepartment _
                          Order By p.Field(Of Integer)("Shown_Period") _
                          Select p.Field(Of Integer)("Num_Int")).ToArray()
    'Add Series to the Chart.
    RateChart.Series.Add(New Series(UserDepartment))
    RateChart.Series(UserDepartment).IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    RateChart.Series(UserDepartment).BorderWidth = 3
    RateChart.Series(UserDepartment).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    RateChart.Series(UserDepartment).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
Next
RateChart.Legends(0).Enabled = True
RateChart.Visible = True
btn_Print.Visible = True
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

PS: it is not fixed for how many department in a table.

Comment: The source data in the question uses "Period_Shown" but the LINQ queries use "Shown_Period".

Comment: A DataGridView is a Windows Forms control. A GridView is an ASP.NET control. Is this an ASP.NET application?

Comment: You should use the data which was used to create the GridView to create the chart, instead of trying to get the data back from the GridView.